# XPath to select elements based on class

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

How do I effectively use the `:not` to select elements in a situation like below:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a b c"/>
    <div class="a"/>
</div>
```

I need to select the div with just class 'a' and exclude the `div` with classes 'a', 'b' and 'c'.
 Thing is the number of `div`'s with the class that I need varies for every load of page and so would have to use logic of finding `div`'s with class 'a' and not having class 'b' and 'c'

Comment: Because you set Xpath - `/div[@class="a"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@class="a"]
```

will select all `div` elements with a `class` attribute equal *exactly* to `"a"`.  It will *not* select `div` elements such as `<div class="a b c"/>`.

It's actually harder to include `div` elements where `a` is among one of the classes selected:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a ')]
```

This takes care to select `<div class="a b c"/>` but not `<div class="abc"/>`

Comment: Thank you @kjughes.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below example code in java.

```
WebElement elm = driver.findElement(By.className("parent"));
WebElement el = elm.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='a' and not(@class='a b c')]"));
el.click();
```

Comment: If it helps you then dont forget to upvote it so that others can get help from this.